# How do i write a mock configuration file in the setUp for my unittesting?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to make my setUp-method create a mock configuration file, write a bunch of mock variables to it, and then use this file to instantiate the class (called Producer) i am running my tests on.

```
path_to_file =("/path/to/unit.Config")
unitTest = open (path_to_file, 'w')
unitTest.write("a string containing mock variables")
prod = Producer("unit.Config")
```

The tests work if i manually create a file and fill it with data prior to running the tests, but doing it in setUp causes my program to crash ("Producer instance has no attribute 'LOGGER'). If i remove the 3 first lines of code the tests will run fine - so writing to the config file works.

Answer (score 1):

To guarantee that the content that you write to a file is actually available to any process reading the file you need to `close` the file handle after writing to it. The easiest way to remember to do this is to use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

```
with open(path_to_file, 'w') as file_pointer:
    file_pointer.write("content")
# Outside the `with` the file content is available
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you closed the file before trying to read the configuration from it you might get better results.